# Adding to existing UINavigationController in iOS / Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an existing navigation controller delegate that places a menu button on each view controller in the app.

```
class MyNavigationControllerDelegate: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        let navItem = viewController.navigationItem
        let menuBtn = MyCustomMenuButton()
         ...
        navItem.setRightBarButton(menuBtn, animated: false)
}
```

This works great...I get a menu button in the nav bar for each view.  But for some views, I'd like to add another button on the right next to the menu button, so I added this:

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let newButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "(+)", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = newButton
   }
}
```

But this has no effect. The menu button is still there but the new button is not added. How should this  be done then?

Comment: I can override the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` in `CustomViewController` but is this the best / only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But this has no effect

Yes, it does. But you don't have time to *see* the effect. You are saying the same thing twice, because `setRightBarButtonItem` is the same as `rightBarButtonItem =...` So whichever one you say second, that is the one that is ultimately obeyed; either way, it rips the existing right bar button item out and replaces it with the other one.

If the goal is to have *multiple* right bar button items, that is what the `rightBarButtonItems` is for (notice the plural). You can call `setRightBarButtonItems` instead (again, notice the plural). Looking to see whether there is *already* a right bar button item and taking that into account is up to you, of course. There is no magical `append` method.

Comment: Using `setRightBarButtonItems` in the delegate file would more tightly couple that delegate with this specific view controller, so I am trying to avoid specifying a particular view controller in the delegate. Right now the solution that works requires duplicate code in the view controller using  `setRightBarButtonItems` there. It works but is sloppy I think.

Comment: Well at this point I don't know what you're talking about. The question was why you were seeing only one right bar button item and I explained that.

Comment: Actually, the question is, "How should this be done," not "why is this happening," but you put me on the right path with, "There is no magical append method."